# Can't change or add keyborad layout in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

I am a new in Ubuntu and still learning to use it. But in some ways I get the error as below and I can't Google it to find an answer. If someone please see this error:

---

```
Error activating XKB configuration. 
There can be various reasons for that.
If you report this situation as a bug, include the results of
xprop -root | grep XKB
gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard model
gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts
gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard options
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kbd
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but key change with alt + ctrl didn't work. Can you help me again??

Comment: what is the shortcut you use alt+ctrl for?